# I added java class to debug ( STRDBG ) but source code is not available

Tags: java, debugging, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to debug java program that I call from RPGILE program on our iSeries machine (V7R2M0 with java 1.7.0) with its good old debugger (STRDBG).
Following [this manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-native-ibm-i-debugger-debug-java-class-invoked-ile-program) it should be possible and I was able to add class I want to debug to modules list:

[image: Modules list]

But when I try to display module source it states "Source not available":

[image: Display module source]
Also when I try to step into java source it does not step inside.

What I tried to do/checked:

1. I checked that I have access to jar file
2. Jar file contains source files with class files
3. I added jar file to

   - /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk71/32bit/lib
   - /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk71/64bit/lib
   - /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk70/32bit/lib
   - /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk70/64bit/lib
4. I added .java file next to jar as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sys.ibm.as400.misc/Lnm7PUDSuac) (see bottom)
5. Jar file is on classpath in both jobs (see [manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-native-ibm-i-debugger-debug-java-class-invoked-ile-program))
6. Java program runs correctly, I just cannot debug it
7. [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sys.ibm.as400.misc/Lnm7PUDSuac) is a mention that I have to first use CRTJVAPGM, but that complains - "Command CRTJVAPGM not valid for current release.". Probably because it is only in QSYSV7R1M0/QSYSV6R1M0 libraries - so it is not a version for V7R2M0.

Is it possible to work with source code here?